# Thousand separator NAN and Infinity JavaScript/ jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor-pages

I am trying to implement a thousand separator while typing in MVC 6 razor page, the code below seems to work but it shows **NAN** if the number is deleted completely and also shows **INFINITY** if a large set of numbers are also entered into the textbox, lastly, it only separates the thousand part, it doesn't add the dot and the hundredth part to it, **e.g: 10000 = 10, 000**, but I want it to be like this: **10000 = 10, 000.00**. I appreciate any assistance.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#TransAmount").on('keyup', function () {
                $(this).val(numberWithCommas(parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ""))));
            });
        });
        function numberWithCommas(x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) instead of reinventing it?

Comment: I don't want to display, I want to thousand separator to happen while typing the digits in a textbox

Comment: You're only triggering on `keyup` but what if somebody copy/pastes into that field using only the mouse?

Comment: I am a backend developer, I don't know much about JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “I don’t want to display”. NumberFormat does precisely what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Can you throw more light on how this could be implemented on HTML textbox to show the digits grouping while the user is typing in figures on the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is to make a masked input for a number. I would NOT recommend to do it yourself, there're already well-established libraries for that.

I recommend `inputmask`:

https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/#/demo